# Pinout of Arduino 9 Axes Motion Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, pins

I bought an [Arduino 9 Axes Motion Shield](http://www.arduino.org/products/arduino-9-axes) without looking at the pinout. I'm worried it won't work with my [Adafruit Motor Shield v1](https://www.adafruit.com/products/81).

It seems the 9 axes shield uses I2C, a reset pin and several other pins for the TinkerKit Input, Output and TWI connectors. Does anyone have a list of specific ports used by the shield on the Arduino UNO?

It also seems that my Arduino UNO r1 only has the original analog pins for I2C, while the 9 axes shield uses the new pins next to the digital pins.

*update: I asked support from arduino.org on twitter and on their forums, no reply yet and it seems their twitter account has been suspended. Should have bought a Genuino I guess.*

Answer (score 1):

The I2C pins on the V3 shield are just copies of A4 & A5 - so just run a jumper wire some way.

BTW that Motion shield looks like it only uses 1 interrupt pin in addition to I2C, so you may be ok.

The motor board does have a library at https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/downloads and you can look at the code to see what it uses.

I personally use the mpu6050 - same kind of thing, I2C one interrupt but only 6DoF (which is plenty).  The 6050 has been superseded with the 9150, 9DoF.  6050 break out boards sell for $6 (or less).  Actually I put all this together on one piece (http://www.spiked3.com/new-products/)